# How to get column names of columns with unique value count greater than a specific number within a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas dataframe and divided the columns in numerical columns and categorical columns. I have named the categorical columns as `cat_cols` . Now I am trying to find the columns within `cat_cols` with number of unique values in them greater than 10.

My code:

```
data[cat_cols].nunique() > 10
```

output

```
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool
```

How do I store column_names `1,2,3` in a list directly?

I have stored them manually, but facing an issue when I loop through the columns. My code

```
cat_cols_with_high_card = ['1','2','3']

for col in cat_cols_with_high_card:
    print('column: '+str(col))
    #data[str(col)]
    data[col].value_counts()
```

Output of this:

```
column: 1
column: 2
column: 3
```

But the data or value counts are not printed, I am suspecting that there might be an issue with the column names being understood as `int`. My cat_cols:

```
print(cat_cols)
```

output

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```

Where am I going wrong? I am using Jupyter Notebook for executions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using your code as the criteria for the columns variable like

`data[cat_cols].loc[:, data[cat_cols].nunique() > 10].columns`

or just

`data.loc[:, data[cat_cols].unique() > 10].columns`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
(data[cat_cols].nunique() > 10).loc[lambda x : x].index.tolist()
```